# List<Long> to int lossy conversion

Tags: java, arrays, list, lossy-compression

I'm trying to solve a challenge and the function must return a long integer and takes an `int` and `List<Long>` as parameters but i keep getting the following error:

```
Solution.java:32: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int
                if (i >= coin) dp[i] += dp[i - coin];
```

I've tried different casting but it all comes back to this. My code is below:

```
public static long count(int n, List<Long> c) {


    long[] dp = new long[n + 1];
    dp[0] = 1;

    for (long coin : c) {
        for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            if (i >= coin) dp[i] += dp[i - coin];
         }
     }
    return dp[n];

   }

}
```

Comment: I should've been more clear, where would i make this change?

Answer (score 1):

Couple problems here:

1. `i` should be an `int` and not a `long` since it is the variable initialized in a `for` loop. If it was a `long`, you'd get a type mismatch error.
2. Since `c` stores instances of `Long`, `coin` should also be a `Long`

Now, since `i` is an `int` and `coin` is a `Long`, you need to cast the difference of the two to an `int` as well.

```
public static long count(int n, List<Long> c) {
    long[] dp = new long[n + 1];
    dp[0] = 1;
    for (Long coin : c) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i >= coin) dp[i] += dp[(int) (i - coin)];
        }
    }
    return dp[n];
}
```